# Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на контейнер с номером странцы, он менял цвет

Tags: php, html

Есть пагинация страниц:

```
<div class="numbers">
                <?php
                if ((!empty(isset($_GET['page'])) && $_GET['page']!="rest") || !empty(isset($_GET['filtertype'])) || !empty(isset($_GET['filtername']))) {
                    $count = ceil($row_cnt / 10);
                    if(isset($_GET['num'])) {
                        $num = $_GET['num'];
                    } else {
                        $num = 1;
                    }
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
                        $params = $_GET;
                        $params['num'] = $i;
                        $query = http_build_query($params);
                        echo "<div class='num'><a href='index.php?" .$query. "'>" . $i . "</a></div>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на номер страницы ($i), контейнер  с этим номером страницы менял цвет фона? (это нужно, чтобы был виден номер активной страницы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JS (jQuery, если у вас ещё и ajax):

$('body').on('click','.num a',function () {

$('.num').removeClass('active');

$(this).addClass('active');

});

css:

.num a.active {

background-color: нужный цвет;

}

php:

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {

                        $params = $_GET;

                        $params['num'] = $i;

                        $query = http_build_query($params);

?>

<div class='num'><a calss='<?= $i == $num ? 'active' : ''?>' href='index.php?<?=$query?>'><?=$i?></a></div>
<?}
```

Comment: благодарю. работает.